# Why does COMSOL treat a well as a rectangular cube?

Tags: comsol, modeling

I'm trying to learn COMSOL for a graduate research project and am struggling through a flow and transport in 3D tutorial. As such I'm walking through my boundary conditions and trying to figure out if I can find something that is wrong in my model.

I noticed that a cylinder, which I've assigned to be a well is treated as an elongate rectangular cube with all 12 edges, and 6 sides as selectable entities. I'm not sure if this is even the route of my problem, but my question is why treat the well as a rectangle instead of a cube?

Some background if it's helpful: my model consists of a simple 100mX100mX10m granite substance with the goal of modelling flow and transport using the well as a mass flow injection well, injecting at a rate of 1X10^6 kg/s. The well is 0.1m in diameter and 10m long.

Comment: We really can't know without you providing more information, but the question I would ask is how you described the geometry of the object? When you generated the mesh, did you start from a cylindrical well, and how many cells do you use to resolve the well?

Comment: The geometry of the well was described as a cylinder (0.1m diameter x 10m long) to start. It's located within the block previously described and meshed using a physics-controlled mesh with a 'finer' element size. I see now that if I simply redefine the elements size as 'Extremely fine', the mesh approximates a cylinder much better. However I'd guess that is much more computationally intensive. I believe this is the answer I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear! Meshing is tricky...